# Can you exclude scanning of a particular app or file on Avast Antivirus for Samsung?

Tags: android, antivirus, antimalware, smartphone

I have Avast pro for my Samsung. I searched the whole app but I cant find the option to exclude/whitelist an app or file from scanning. Is there such an option for android? I looked through their website and only for PC they have the option to exclude scanning. They don't have a guide for android and I cant seem to find anything regarding this on the internet.

Is exclusion of app/file scanning possible for smartphones on Avast Antivirus?